# Does Ahlfors–David regularity of a measure imply its Fourier asymptotic behavior?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $R^d$. If $\mu$ satisfies $\mu(B(x,r))\le Cr^\alpha$ for any $x\in R^d$ and $r>0$, then Strichartz (Fourier asymptotics of fractal measures, J. Funct. Anal. 1990) proved that
$$\limsup\limits_{R\to \infty}\frac{1}{R^{d-\alpha}}\int_{|x|\le R}|\widehat{\mu}(x)|^2dx\le C_2.$$
Here $\widehat{\mu}(x)=\int e^{-2\pi itx}d\mu(t)$ is the Fourier transformation of $\mu.$

My question is: if $\mu$ is Ahlfors–David regular, i.e., $C^{-1}r^\alpha\le\mu(B(x,r))\le Cr^\alpha$ for any $x\in R^d$ and $r>0$, can we have
$$C_1\le  \liminf\limits_{R\to \infty}\frac{1}{R^{d-\alpha}}\int_{|x|\le R}|\widehat{\mu}(x)|^2dx\le\limsup\limits_{R\to \infty}\frac{1}{R^{d-\alpha}}\int_{|x|\le R}|\widehat{\mu}(x)|^2dx\le C_2?$$

Here $C, C_1, C_2$ are all constants.

Does someone know related results or can prove it? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like necessarily $\alpha = d$, right? Or did you mean "for any $x$ in the support of $\mu$" rather than "for any $x \in R^d$"?

Comment: Thanks! @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki I mean for any $x$ in the support of $\mu$. I also think if $\alpha=d,$ then the inequalities hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(There are some details missing in this answer. Time permitting, I will try to expand it.)

It suffices to find a *non-negative* continuous function $\phi$ with $\phi(0) > 0$ and Fourier transform bounded and supported in $B(0, 1)$. In dimension one, $\phi(x) = (1 - \cos x)/(\pi x^2)$, $\hat\phi(z) = (1 - |z|)_+$ is a good example.

Then $\phi_R(x) = R^d \phi(R x)$ has Fourier transform $\hat\phi(R^{-1} z)$ supported in $B(0, R)$, and we have
$$ \int_{|z| \le R} |\hat\mu(z)|^2 dz \ge \frac{1}{\|\hat\phi\|_\infty} \int_{|z| \le R} |\hat\phi_R(z) \hat\mu(z)|^2 dz = \frac{2\pi}{\|\hat\phi\|_\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\mu * \phi_R(x)|^2 dx $$
by Plancherel's theorem. Now, $\phi(x) \ge C_1 \mathbb{1}_{B(0, r)}(x)$ for some $C_1, r > 0$, and hence
$$ \int_{|z| \le R} |\hat\mu(z)|^2 dz \ge \frac{2 \pi C_1 R^{2d}}{\|\hat\phi\|_\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\mu * \mathbb{1}_{B(0, r/R)}(x)|^2 dx . $$
Ahlfors regularity implies that $\mu * \mathbb{1}_{B(0, r/R)}(x) \ge C_2 (r/R)^\alpha$ on a set of measure at least $C_3 (r/R)^{d-\alpha}$ (see *Edit* below). We conclude that
$$ \int_{|z| \le R} |\hat\mu(z)|^2 dz \ge \frac{C_1 R^{2d}}{\|\hat\phi\|_\infty} \, (C_2 (r/R)^{\alpha})^2 C_3 (r / R)^{d - \alpha} = C_4 R^{d - \alpha} , $$
as desired.

---

*Edit:* If $r > 0$, then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mu * \mathbb{1}_{B(0, r)}(x) dx = C_1 r^d \mu(\mathbb R^d) $$
(by Fubini), and
$$ \mu * \mathbb{1}_{B(0, r)}(x) = \mu(B(x, r)) \leqslant C_2 r^\alpha $$
for every $x$ (by Ahlfors regularity). (Well, we assume this for $x$ in the support of $\mu$ only, but extension to general $x$ is standard.) It follows that the Lebesgue measure of
$$ \{ x : \mu(B(x, r)) > 0 \} $$
is at least $C_3 r^{d - \alpha}$. However, if $\mu(B(x, r)) > 0$, then $\mu(B(x, 2r)) \geqslant C_4 r^\alpha$ (again by Ahlfors regularity). We conclude that
$$ \mu * \mathbb{1}_{B(0, 2 r)}(x) \geqslant C_4 r^\alpha \quad \text{on a set of Lebesgue measure at least } C_3 r^{d - \alpha} . $$
This is of course equivalent to the property used in the answer above.

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki Many thanks! Would you like to give more comments on the claim that $\mu \ast 1_{B(0,r/R)}\ge C_2 (r/R)^\alpha$ on a set of measure at least $C_3(r/R)^{d-\alpha}$?

Comment: @ljjpfx: I added a short comment about that. Let me know if anything is unclear (or plainly wrong).

Comment: @ Mateusz Kwaśnicki :Thank you very much! It looks nice!